# ElasticSearch what analyzer should be used for searching for both url fragment and exact url path

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to store uri in a mapping and I want to make it searchable the following way:

- Exact match (i.e. if I stored: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions` then looking for the term `http://stackoverflow.com/questions` retrieves the item.
- Bit like letter tokenizer all "words" should be searchable. So searching for either `questions`, `stackoverflow` or maybe `com` will bring back `http://stackoverflow.com/questions` as a hit.
- Looking for '.' or '/' separated url fragments should be still searchable. So searching for `stackoverflow.com` will bring back `http://stackoverflow.com/questions` as a hit.
- should be case insensitive. (like lowercase)
- The `html://`, `htmls://`, `www.` etc. is optional for searching. So searching for either `http://stackoverflow.com` or `stackoverflow.com` will bring back `http://stackoverflow.com/questions` as a hit.

Maybe a solution should be something like chaining tokenizers or something like that. I'm quite new to ES so this is maybe a trivial question.
So what kind of analyzer should I use/build to achieve this functionality?

Any help would be greatly apprechiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely, correct. You will want to set your field type as [multi_field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/multi-field-type/) and then create analyzers for each scenario. At the core, you can then do a [multi_match](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/multi-match-query/) query:

```
=============type properties===============
{
    "fun_documents": {
        "properties": {
            "url": {
                "type": "multi_field",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "keyword"
                    },
                    "alphanum_only": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "my_custom_alpha_num_analyzer"
                    },
                    {
                        "etc": "etc"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

==================query=====================
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "stackoverflow",
            "fields": [
                "url.keyword",
                "url.alphanum_only",
                "url.optional_fun"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you can get fancy with multi_field aliases and reusing the same name, but this is the simple demonstration.